# adding external sqlite databases to my application do not show the whole tables how to fix that?

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

i am creating android application that have sqlite database that i need to add it to the application this database contain 6 tables but when i use the **adb shell** it show only 2 tables how to fix this problem and what i am doing wrong??.

**my sqlite database need to be created on the oncreate method so it must be pre_populated**

## ExternalDBOpenHelper.java

```
package com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static String DB_PATH;

    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;

        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }


    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }

        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

## MatchScheduleList.java

```
package com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MatchScheduleList extends ListActivity {

     private static final String DB_NAME = "world_cup.db";
     // *****Tables name**************************//
    // private static final String TABLE_NAME = "place";


     //*****Tbale name******************************//
        private static final String PLACE_ID = "_id";
        //private static final String NAME_NAME = "name";
        private static final String CITY_NAME = "city";


        private SQLiteDatabase database;
        private ListView listView;
        private ArrayList<String> places;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_demo_for_match);

           ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
            database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();


        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.match_schedule_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you recently added New tables then you must uninstall app and install app again so that copy New DB from your `Assets` to your `PATH` and you make sure that your New DB contains all 6 tables.

Comment: one thing would be check whether you are picking correct database file.. and if you are frequently adding and removing tables then everytime you need to uninstall and install the app as `onCreate` is called only once at the time of installation.

Comment: thank you this was the problem i must uninstall the app and re install it

Answer (score 0):

It mostly seems that you have updated your database later on. This means that you need to reflect changes back to the android phone using the **onUpgrade method()**. 
Assign a Database Version to your database as a static String. Whenever you create changes to your database make sure that you increse the number in the database Version String.
Here' an example

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =89;
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    //Do this for all 6 of your database tables
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
    //Do this for all 6 tables
    }
```